# Chrome Incognito Mode not blocked despite modifying registry

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, windows-registry

Following the instructions [here](http://www.internetsafetyproject.org/wiki/how-disable-incognito-mode-chrome) and elsewhere, I've been trying to disable Incognito mode to no avail. I've modified the registry for Windows 8.1 Pro x64 as seen as below and despite that, when I restarted my computer to make sure it took effect I could still right click Chrome in my taskbar and hit 'Incognito Mode' and use it as a browser and go to say, google.com

Is this a bug or is it not possible to block Chrome's Incognito Mode anymore outside of uninstalling Chrome?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Chrome page](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability) that describes the various policy settings has this note:

> Note: Starting with Chromium 28, policies are loaded directly from the
>   Group Policy API on Windows. Policies manually written to the registry
>   will be ignored. See http://crbug.com/259236 for details.